# How to add next and previous button --- Turn.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

Created a demo of flipbook using turn.js which is working fine if I tap on the corners.

I need to add the next and previous button which is a feature of turns js, but am unable to add it.

Can anyone help me out.

JS:

```
$("#flipbook").turn({
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    autoCenter: true,
    next:true
});
```

[demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/A9a7E/7913/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery Turn library supports [methods](http://www.turnjs.com/docs/Turn_Methods) to explicitly turn the page.

To fulfill your requirement, we can add two buttons, bind click events on them and call the Turn library methods (named "next" and "previous") respectively.

Check this [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A9a7E/7914/).

HTML (adding two buttons):

```
<div class="flip-control">
    <a href="#" id="prev"> Previous </a>
    <a href="#" id="next"> Next </a>
</div>
```

CSS (applying styles) :

```
div.flip-control {
    width: 400px;
    text-align: center;
}

div.flip-control a {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

JavaScript :

```
var oTurn = $("#flipbook").turn({
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    autoCenter: true,
    next:true
});

$("#prev").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    oTurn.turn("previous");
});

$("#next").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    oTurn.turn("next");
});
```

Comment: I would like to ask how do you disable previous tag when it is on the first page and disable the next tag on the last page.

Comment: how to horizontaly center the entire book ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.sj-book').turn('previous');
```

OR

```
$('.sj-book').turn('next');
```

And You will be happy!

Happy New Year!
С новым годом!